# How to hide the undrlying data in a ggplot scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a scatter plot in ggplot and would like to loose the points and show only the smooth line and the confidence interval. I checked `geom_point()` function and there is no option for turning it off such that the points/underlying data is hidden. Any suggestions? much appreciated.

Joseph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot smooth line with confidence interval around the line you should use `geom_smooth()`. This will smoothed line using loess if there are less than 1000 observations and gam if more. But you can change smoothing method with argument `method=`.

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(wt,mpg))+geom_smooth()
```

[image]